# Spring Integration Kafka slow message processing when using KafkaNativeOffsetManager

Tags: spring-integration, apache-kafka

We've been using SI Kafka for a new project here with much success. Prior to a recent switch, we were using the KafkaTopicOffsetManager for the management of our consumers topic offset. In order to not have additional topics per consumer/topic pair and to use Burrow or lag monitoring, we decided to use the latest KafkaNativeOffsetManager that uses the native offset management provided by Kafka. After making the switch though, we noticed that the consumption of messages from the target topic was continually lagging behind. We know this didn't happen with the KafkaTopicOffsetManager as we were using it for months prior to the switch. We also ran side-by-side tests and verified that the consumption of messages was in near real time with the production of messages when using KafkaTopicOffsetManager and the KafkaNativeOffsetManager was always increasingly lagging behind. Both offset managers are using default configuration and are both committing offsets after the message is processed (auto-acknowledge).

So I really have two questions, the first not be the primary of this SO post.

First question is why would this be the case that the native offset management is slower than using a topic for offset management?

Second question is, can we configure SI kafka to not commit offsets on the successful processing of each message but rather provide a different strategy? Our thought was that maybe we shouldn't be committing offsets so frequently and should be either doing them as batch update. For example, commit offsets after successfully processing 25 messages or after 30 seconds.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When disabling autocommit and receiving the acknowledgment header, the only thing you need to do is to invoke `acknowledge()` once your message has been processed. This assumes that even if you are handling the message in a different thread, you will retain a reference to the `Acknowledgment` instance, either as such, or as part of the original `Message` - or you are copying headers if you are doing transformations. But the call needs to be made by your code.

Secondly, the performance issue - it is caused by the fact that the `KafkaNativeOffsetManager` implementation makes a blocking, relatively more expensive call to the brokers (relative to the simply sending a message to a compacted topic, as the `KafkaTopicOffsetManager` does. Generally speaking doing updates after every message is expensive, and in Spring XD we mitigate that by using https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/master/extensions/spring-xd-extension-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/x/kafka/WindowingOffsetManager.java, which reduces the number of effective writes. I suppose we could do something similar for Spring Integration.

To wit: comparatively, 100000 updates complete in 9.8s with the `KafkaNativeOffsetManager` and in 0.382s with the `KafkaTopicOffsetManager`, as shown by https://github.com/mbogoevici/spring-integration-kafka/blob/perftest/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/kafka/performance/OffsetManagerPerformanceTests.java (results gathered on my own machine). Results may be skewed somehow, but still indicate a big difference. Tracing in YourKit confirms the result.

Comment: Thank you. see my comments to the other answer. We ended up turning autocommit offsets off and processing the offset down the integration flow, only committing every 10th offset or last offset after 1 second of inactivity. however this has its own problems. for example if you have a stream of events and your flow only cares about 10% of the messages and drops the rest, then the down flow component doesn't receive the ack and then the offset isnt committed. I'm sure this could be resolved with additional flow symmantics but we may just turn autocommit back on and only commit every 10th offset.

Comment: i will take a look at the WindowingOffsetManager and see if that suits our needs. thank you.

Comment: marking this as the write answer because it talks about the performance differences, the means to commit offsets later as well as the windowing strategy that is similar in concept to the one we ultimately chose. We'll likely move to use the Windowing offset manager or something similar. it would be nice if this was available directly in SI Kafka

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what's the problem with the `KafkaNativeOffsetManager`, would be great if you share some investigation on the matter, some bottleneck place in our code in the [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INTEXT).

For the deferred offset commit I can suggest `autoCommitOffset = false` on the `KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`. Having that the sent to the `channel` message will be enriched with the `KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT` header in face of `DefaultAcknowledgment`. It really answers to your request:

```
/**
 * Invoked when the message for which the acknowledgment has been created has been processed.
 * Calling this method implies that all the previous messages in the partition have been processed already.
 */
void acknowledge();
```

Comment: for the first, we were thinking of creating a test that has two threads, one using the KafkaTopicOffsetManager and the other the KafkaNativeOffsetManager that would both try to write offsets as fast as possible for about 500,000 iterations and see which does it better. Our thought isn't that its necessarily with the Spring code so may also be worth trying with native Kafka client. Question was more around if this behavior has been seen and explained.

Comment: for the second, we are aware of disabling the auto commit, but what is not clear to me is how the offset then gets committed. Does there need to be something in the message flow that needs to receive the message and determine if the offset should be committed (e.g. kafka | handler | handler | ... | handler (commit kafka offset) | output handler)?

Comment: so we did end up testing this and verified the native was seemingly much slower than the topic based. After digging in, we were thinking that the two offset managers weren't comparable. Reason being that the topic offset manager writes is offsets asynchronously and does not wait for a response before returning control. its possible that the thread pool runs the async writes was backing up. this could then look like the one was out performing the other but in reality, its possible that the offsets were being written at the same speed.

Comment: This lead us to think that using the topic based offset management is not safe. as processing of messages was not one-to-one with the committing of those messages offsets. This could be wrong, but we ended up going down a different path anyways. Thoughts?

Comment: That was the point: do not commit offsets for each message but do that periodically for some range. With the new Spring Kafka project we are fully based on the native offset commit and provide the strategies like: http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/1.0.0.M1/reference/htmlsingle/#_committing_offsets. Where a `BATCH`-aware commits are the best choice. With Kafka you don't lose messages anyway. You only may think about the Idempotent Receiver: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#idempotent-receiver do not process the same message twice.

Comment: is there a relative target release date for the new spring-kafka and spring-integration-kafka?

Comment: See this: https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/11/spring-integration-kafka-support-2-0-0-m1-is-now-available. I think somewhere in the middle of May all we will see GA!